# Truncate on specific paragraph without images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Simple one - how to truncate text of a blogpost on (let's say) 3rd paragraph? And tell it explicitly not render images?**

I am using markdown btw. Can this be done in some 'elegant' way with simple code and no external gems in pure ruby?

If not, how to best implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For truncating paragraphs something like the following should work:

```
def truncate_by_paragraph(text, num=3)
  # since I'm not sure if the text will have \r, \n or both I'm swapping
  # all \r characters for \n, then splitting at the newlines and removing
  # any blank characters from the array
  array = text.gsub("\r", "\n").split("\n").reject { |i| i == "" }
  array.take(num).join("\n") + ".." # only 2 dots since sentence will already have 1
end
```

To remove images you can do the following:

```
def remove_images(text)
  text.gsub(/<img([^>])+/, "")
end
```

Then you can do

```
truncate_by_paragraph(@text) # will return first 3 paragraphs
truncate_by_paragraph(@text, 5) # will return first 5 paragraphs
remove_images(truncate_by_paragraph(@text)) # 3 paragraphs + no images
```

Depending on the formatting you're after you might want to change the `join` in the first method to `join("\n\n")` to get double spacing.

Also if you really want `...` at the end of the text you might want to test whether the 3rd paragraph has a dot or not, or maybe it already has 3.

Comment: and what about ommiting images?